# What is the difference between 閉​め​る (shimeru) and くれ​る (kureru)?

Tags: words

What is the difference between 閉める ([shimeru](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=shimeru&e=&search=Search%20%3E)) and くれる ([kureru](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=kureru&e=&search=Search%20%3E))? Both mean close, but when would you use one over the other.

Please explain making reference to these examples:

Example 1:

```
(私が)寒いので、窓を閉めてください
(watashi ga) samui no de, mado o shimete kudasai 
Please close the window because I am cold
```

Example 2:

```
もう少し窓を閉めてくれませんか
mō sukoshi mado o shimete kuremasen ka
Please close the window more
```

Why does one use  閉​め​る ([shimeru](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=shimeru&e=&search=Search%20%3E)) and the other uses くれ​る ([kureru](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=kureru&e=&search=Search%20%3E))?

Comment: Um, don't both use 閉める?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **both** your examples the verb to close is 閉める.

The くれる you are seeing in example 2 has nothing to do with closing. 
窓を閉めてくれませんか literally means "won't you give me (the favour of) closing the window". くれる means "to give" and it is one of the famous giving and receiving verbs that are explained in many books and online tutorials.

くれる apparently does have a meaning of "to close" as in to come to an end, but I'm not familiar with its usage, and it is certainly not the meaning in your example.